# Airflow logs have a lot of asterisk characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, airflow

Hi I have setup Airflow on my local using docker-compose, I am using MAC and airflow docker version is `apache/airflow:2.1.0`. The logs for tasks have a lot asterisk as shown below. I need help to rectify it, I searched a lot but could not find anything.

```
*** Reading local file: /opt/airflow/logs/bi_sf_snowflake/git_clone/2021-07-09T11:41:24.189880+00:00/1.log
[2021-07-09 11:41:28,633] {logging_mixin.py:104} WARNING - ***-***-***-*** ***L***o***g***g***i***n***g*** ***e***r***r***o***r*** ***-***-***-***
[2021-07-09 11:41:28,634] {logging_mixin.py:104} WARNING - ***T***r***a***c***e***b***a***c***k*** ***(***m***o***s***t*** ***r***e***c***e***n***t*** ***c***a***l***l*** ***l***a***s***t***)***:***
[2021-07-09 11:41:28,635] {logging_mixin.py:104} WARNING - *** *** ***F***i***l***e*** ***"***/***u***s***r***/***l***o***c***a***l***/***l***i***b***/***p***y***t***h***o***n***3***.***6***/***l***o***g***g***i***n***g***/***_***_***i***n***i***t***_***_***.***p***y***"***,*** ***l***i***n***e*** ***9***9***4***,*** ***i***n*** ***e***m***i***t***
```

The docker-compose file starts as below -

```yaml
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-mc-airflow:Dockerfile}
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
  volumes:
    - ./dags/:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}"
  depends_on:
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy
  command: bash -c pip
```

The airflow config has below log config

```py
logging_level = INFO

# Logging level for Flask-appbuilder UI.
#
# Supported values: ``CRITICAL``, ``ERROR``, ``WARNING``, ``INFO``, ``DEBUG``.
fab_logging_level = WARN

# Logging class
# Specify the class that will specify the logging configuration
# This class has to be on the python classpath
# Example: logging_config_class = my.path.default_local_settings.LOGGING_CONFIG
logging_config_class =

# Flag to enable/disable Colored logs in Console
# Colour the logs when the controlling terminal is a TTY.
colored_console_log = False

# Log format for when Colored logs is enabled
colored_log_format = [%%(blue)s%%(asctime)s%%(reset)s] {%%(blue)s%%(filename)s:%%(reset)s%%(lineno)d} %%(log_color)s%%(levelname)s%%(reset)s - %%(log_color)s%%(message)s%%(reset)s
colored_formatter_class = airflow.utils.log.colored_log.CustomTTYColoredFormatter

# Format of Log line
log_format = [%%(asctime)s] {%%(filename)s:%%(lineno)d} %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s
simple_log_format = %%(asctime)s %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s

# Specify prefix pattern like mentioned below with stream handler TaskHandlerWithCustomFormatter
# Example: task_log_prefix_template = {ti.dag_id}-{ti.task_id}-{execution_date}-{try_number}
task_log_prefix_template =

# Formatting for how airflow generates file names/paths for each task run.
log_filename_template = {{ ti.dag_id }}/{{ ti.task_id }}/{{ ts }}/{{ try_number }}.log

# Formatting for how airflow generates file names for log
log_processor_filename_template = {{ filename }}.log

# full path of dag_processor_manager logfile
dag_processor_manager_log_location = /opt/airflow/logs/dag_processor_manager/dag_processor_manager.log

# Name of handler to read task instance logs.
# Defaults to use ``task`` handler.
task_log_reader = task

# A comma\-separated list of third-party logger names that will be configured to print messages to
# consoles\.
# Example: extra_loggers = connexion,sqlalchemy
extra_loggers =
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in Airflow 2.1.1 already. It was caused by secret masker that incorrectly masked "no character" if your connection had empty password.

The ways to fix it:

- migrate to latest released Airflow (best)
- disable secrets masking (new feature in Airflow 2.1.0)
- find the connection that had empty password and set it to some non-empty password (usually for those connections password value is not used so you can set it to any random set of characters).

The issue in question is here: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16007

Comment: None of the connections have empty passwords and upgrading to 2.1.1 is giving other issue `Invalid JSON configuration, must be a dict`. Issue here https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/16648